# Slow WCF: 500ms for "void Test()"

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

I have a WCF service hosted by a Windows Service. It works but calling it is very slow: A simple function like `void Test()` takes around 500 ms from client call to server receive.

I tried several different configurations but haven't succeeded in making that faster. Both client and server are on the same machine.

Here is the code:

`Shared.dll`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Test();
}
```

`Server.exe`:

```
public class Service : IContract
{
    public void Test()
    {
        this.Log("Test: " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
    }
}
```

`Client.exe`:

```
var binding = ...;
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IContract>(binding, "net.tcp://localhost/Service");
var service = factory.CreateChannel();
this.Log("Test: " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
service.Test();
```

`app.config`:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Server.Service">
      <endpoint address="Service" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcp" contract="Shared.IContract">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="NetTcp" portSharingEnabled="true">
        <security mode="None">
          <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
          <transport protectionLevel="None" clientCredentialType="None"/>
        </security>
        <reliableSession enabled="false" />
      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

### Edit

I am currently testing this with client and server in the same machine but the idea is to have them in different machine for production.

The factory and channel creations are not the culprit here. I ruled that out putting a `Thread.Sleep(20000)` between the creation and the log and got the same result.

The difference between the client log and the server log is around 500 ms for the first call (actually, it's anywhere between 300 ms and 1 second) but then, it lasts less than 5 ms for any more call to `Test()`. I want my function to be always very fast, including the first call. How can I do that?

Comment: You do realize that `var service = new ChannelFactory<IContract>().CreateChannel()` has its own overhead, right?  It will _not_ be instantaneous.

Comment: Of course. In the code you'll see that I log the time after creating the channel.

Comment: You're creating a new `ChannelFactory<T>` in that statement - do you do this for every call?  You should create the instance of the channel factory one time - you can call `CreateChannel()` multiple times against that instance.  Otherwise you're going to pay (unnecessary) overhead on every call because you are recreating the channel factory.

Comment: I'm only creating it once. I just found out that the call to Test() takes 500 ms only the first time: if I do it again, it's less than 5 ms. Any idea how to prevent the first call to be that long?

Comment: So new takes 500 ms.  Don't wait for the first call to new.  New in the ctor.  For on machine named pipes is faster.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx

Comment: Try breaking the statement where you construct the channel factory and create the channel into two statements.  First construct the channel factory (where most of the overhead is), and then get a channel from the factory and see if that speeds it up.  I.e., `var factory = new ChannelFactory<IContract>();` and then `var service = factory.CreateChannel();`

Comment: @Blam: new doesn't take 500 ms, the first call of `Test()` does. Also, this program is intended to work with clients on different machines which is why I'm using NetTcp.

Comment: @Tim: the overhead is not on the factory or channel creation. My real code breaks them in several parts: the client does not use the `app.config` but rather creates the factory using code (same configuration but use code instead of config).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using the Datetime.Now's to measure this, I would recommend a different approach for benchmarking.

```
    var elapsedTimes = new List<long>();
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        stopwatch.Reset();
        stopwatch.Start();

        service.Test();

        stopwatch.Stop();
        elapsedTimes.Add(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    Log("Average time for Test(): " + elapsedTimes.Average() + "ms");
```

Also, the first call always seems to be slow, probably because of initializations taking place on the service side. Try making one call to service.Test() and then running this benchmark.

Please post your results, I'd be curious to found out how it goes.

Comment: I didn't use the stopwatch because I wanted to measure the time from client to server only.
Indeed the subsequent calls are much faster (~2ms). I've tried several things to make it quicker (such as using a generated XmlSerializer) but that didn't help at all. I haven't found a way to force the channel initialization before calling any contract function, so I think I'll create a dummy function (`void Init()`) that I will call at startup and then use my service normally.